# Is there any ftp command to resume upload?

Tags: ftp

Oh! with my slow net connection, I am badly stuck. I was uploading a video file from local box to remote one via ftp. But net failed.I know there is a command named reget to resume download but Is there any command to resume upload.?
If no then I am hit.

Comment: You can try to use the REST command followed by STOR. In theory it should work, but I never used it myself.

Comment: `wput` is an uploader that matches wiht `wget` so it can continue interrupted uploads...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I always use the `lftp` client which has the ability to resume a download that either died midstream or that I want to cancel and later restart.

I usually use the command like so:

```
$ lftp -e "mirror -c /download/<dir> /local/<dir>" -u user -p <port> ftp.server.com
```

#### What else?

This tool's name is a bit misleading, it can handle either FTP or SFTP.

*ftp*

```
$ lftp -e "mirror -c /download/<dir> /local/<dir>" -u user ftp://ftp.server.com
```

*sftp*

```
$ lftp -e "mirror -c /download/<dir> /local/<dir>" -u user sftp://sftp.server.com
```

#### Mirroring Links

From time to time you might encounter a issue with mirroring directories that contain symlinks, to work around this issue you can add this option to your `lftp` command:

```
set ftp:list-options -L
```

For eg:

```
$ lftp -e "set ftp:list-options -L; mirror -c /download/<dir> /local/<dir>" \
    -u user ftp://ftp.server.com
```

#### References

- [lftp man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)
- [Re: [lftp] Mirror not detecting change in remote symlinked file](https://www.mail-archive.com/lftp@uniyar.ac.ru/msg04304.html)

Comment: Great!!working superb!! Many thanks to you slm. The display is very nice as it is showing the rate of transfer, how much downloaded, estimated time left, etc.

Comment: @Ravi - yeah it's the best terminal ftp/sftp client I've found thus far. I often have to do downloads that take 1-2 weeks so running it inside of `screen` makes it easy to come back and check on it, but leave it running. Please accept this answer if you think it solves your Q, and thanks for the Q's.

Comment: (I am sorry) as I am new to this site, I wasn't aware that there is specific way to mark this answer as accepted. Now I have come to know and hence marked this as accepted answer. Many many thanks to help me when yesterday I highly needed a solution.

Answer (score 5):

lftp also has the "reput" command, which does the SIZE and REST for you

```
lftp user:pass@host/path/to/folder
cd ok, cwd=/path/to/folder  
lftp user@host:/path/to/folder> reput file.ext 
---> TYPE I                                
<--- 200 Type set to I
---> SIZE file.ext
<--- 213 11842837120
---> PASV
<--- 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,211,14,15,220,70).
---- Connecting data socket to (10.211.14.15) port 56390
---- Data connection established
---> ALLO 20769244058
<--- 202 No storage allocation necessary
---> REST 11842837120
<--- 350 Restarting at 11842837120. Send STORE or RETRIEVE to initiate transfer
---> STOR file.ext
<--- 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file.ext
`file.ext' at 6756302848 (32%) 31.50M/s eta:7m [Sending data]
```

Comment: if `lftp` is not available, `sftp` also has `reput`

Answer (score 2):

To resume a single file upload using the built-in ftp command you will need to know how many bytes of the file you have already sent. This should be accessible by using `ls`. Then you use the following sequence to restart your upload replacing `<#>` with the number of bytes already sent and `<filename>` with the filename you are uploading.

```
restart <#>
put <filename>
```

If the server allows it  you should receive a message such as the following...

```
350 Restart position accepted (<#>).
150 Ok to send data.
```

This will resume your upload.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed! Works for downloading (receiving) files too; just use `get <filename>` instead of `put <filename>` :)

Answer (score 0):

To resume the transfer of a single file, this seems to work:

1. In your local directory, get the size of the file that was already partially downloaded with:

   ```
   ls -la
   ```
2. Assuming that the folder where the file was partially downloaded is your current directory and that it is at the root of your remote FTP account, adapt the following lftp call to your needs:

   ```
   lftp -e "get1 -c --source-region 2000000000-5000000000 --target-position 2000000000 yourfile.ext" -u utilisateur,mot_de_passe ftp.yourserver.ext
   ```

Running `get1` with the `-c` option resumes the transfer and displays the percentage of the source file that was already downloaded. I haven't finished downloading a resumed file yet, but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, *utilisateur* is French for "user" and *mot de passe* is "password".

Answer (score 0):

Probably, I'm too dump to configure **lftp** properly and that's why I prefer **wput**.
Here is an  example how wput continues upload after connection problems:

```
wput -v -u -B upload.zip ftp://login:pass@server.com/dir/upload.zip
--20:14:23-- `upload.zip'
    => ftp://login:xxxxx@111.111.111.111:21/dir/upload.zip
Connecting to 111.111.111.111:21... connected! 
Logging in as login ... Logged in!
==> CWD dir
==> TYPE I ... done.
==> SIZE upload.zip ... done (4313 bytes)
==> PASV ... done.
==> REST 3584 ... done.
==> STOR upload.zip ... done.
Length: 902,153,406 [902,149,822 to go]
 7% [======>                                                                                         ] 65,658,368       194.0K/s ETA  1:10hError: Error encountered during uploading data (Operation now in progress)
==> ABOR ... Error: recv() timed out. No data received
Receive-Warning: read() timed out. Read '' so far.
failed.
Waiting 10 seconds... Error: recv() timed out. No data received
Receive-Warning: read() timed out. Read '' so far.
Connecting to 111.111.111.111:21... connected! 
Logging in as login ... Logged in!
==> CWD dir
==> TYPE I ... done.
==> SIZE upload.zip ... done (65247144 bytes)
==> PASV ... done.
==> REST 65246208 ... done.
==> STOR upload.zip ... done.
Length: 902,153,406 [836,907,198 to go]
 9% [++++++==>
```

Just to be completely fair, here is my attempt to use lftp for same task:

```
lftp -e "set net:timeout 10; set ssl:check-hostname false; set ssl:verify-certificate false; put -c -O /dir upload.zip; bye" -u login,password server.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single file transfer resume using `curl`:

```
curl -C - --upload-file source_file ftp://destination.server.com/
```

From man page:

```
       -C, --continue-at <offset>
              Continue/Resume a previous file transfer at  the  given  offset.  The
              given  offset  is  the  exact  number  of bytes that will be skipped,
              counting from the beginning of the source file before  it  is  trans‐
              ferred to the destination.  If used with uploads, the FTP server com‐
              mand SIZE will not be used by curl.

              Use "-C -" to tell curl to automatically find out where/how to resume
              the  transfer.  It  then  uses the given output/input files to figure
              that out.

              If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
```